# opinion of - ambiguous?

Tags: prepositions

**Do you have an opinion of Jack?**

It means whether the person has their opinion about Jack. But can it also mean "Do you have an opinion from Jack?"

- one extra question "Does "an opinion by Jack" make sense?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questioner is clearly asking what you think of Jack.

To make it crystal clear that that's what you mean, you could replace the 'of' with an 'on', which would be just as good, but it's not at all necessary.

If, on the other hand, you want to ask about whether the listener shares any of Jack's opinions, there are lots of ways of doing that, including (funnily enough) "do you share any of Jack's opinions?".

If you want to ask about whether you share a specific, preidentified opinion of Jack's, then your first port of call would be "Do you agree with Jack [on xyz]?" though there are any other number of other ways of expressing that.

One realistic example among many dozens might be: "Do you concur with Jack's opinion [on xyz]?"

One would have to say "Do you have Jack's opinion?" is probably grammatically correct, but for a variety of reasons I don't think it's very elegant and I'm pretty sure very few native speakers would put the question that way.

"An opinion by Jack" would seem to me a little unnatural unless you interpret the "opinion" either as a written account of a professional's opinion on a particular technical question or as short for an opinion article in a newspaper or magazine.

In either case, Jack would be the author of the text.

Comment: OK. So, "This is an opinion of Jack" can't mean "This is an opinion from Jack"?

Comment: I wouldn't say "of Jack"; I'd make a Saxon genitive out of him: "This is an opinion of Jack's"  "This is an opinion from Jack" is fine, but it emphasises the provenance of the opinion; that I actually got this opinion from Jack, not simply that Jack has this opinion.  It wouldn't be used very often imo.